# How does focusable affect mouse event raising and handling?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm a little confused as to why setting focusable=false on scrollviewer lets the scrollviewer receive the mousedown event. Could someone explain how focus affects mouse events?

Also, what exactly is the process of mouse event raising? I assume, hit testing is done on the main window, then it progresses through the visual tree and finds the element with the highest zindex and raises a previewmousedown event with the element as its target. The previewmousedown event then tunnels to the target, the target handles it and fires a mousedown event which bubbles upward till it reaches the visual tree's root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of focus: keyboard focus and logical focus. Quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969768.aspx):

> Keyboard focus refers to the element that receives keyboard input and logical focus refers to the element in a focus scope that has focus. The Keyboard class is concerned primarily with keyboard focus and the FocusManager is concerned primarily with logical focus, but this is not an absolute distinction. An element that has keyboard focus will also have logical focus, but an element that has logical focus does not necessarily have keyboard focus. This is apparent when you use the Keyboard class to set the element that has keyboard focus, for it also sets logical focus on the element.

In this case, `ScrollViewer` can accept or reject the logical focus, it is associated with keyboard focus. Default control usually has `Focusable="True"`, the same applies to `ScrollViewer`.

That is, when `Focusable="True"`, `ScrollViewer` has a dotted box (with logical focus):

[image]

When `Focusable="False"` `ScrollViewer` does not have a dotted box, because now he does not accept the logical focus. You can also customize the look of focus, with the help of `FocusVisualStyle`.

As you can see, there is no mention of the events of the mouse, the only events that can affect it - it's a keyboard event. The events did not trigger, you need to set the element `IsEnabled="False"`, or block the event call using `e.Handled = true;`:

```
private void ScrollViewer_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;

    MessageBox.Show("MouseDown!"); // now when you click, it will not be displayed
}
```

As for your second question, I think you correctly wrote.